# sometimes - Socket Error 10054 from email server, SMTP Client

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I have a weird issue but not sure what to make of it,

I have a .net console application that prepares some data and FTP's it over
after the operation is complete it's supposed to send out a confirmation email - only what happens is that sometimes email is recieved, sometimes not

the application runs under a schedulear from SQL Job Agent using sql server 2014
the app is on the same server as the database , owner is sa and job is run under SQL Server agent - SQLSERVERAGENT has all the rights on the folder

Mail server being used is MDaemon, checking on the server logs it reveals that:

```
Fri 2016-08-12 06:28:50.387: 01: ----------
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.154: 05: Session 834167; child 0001
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.154: 05: Accepting SMTP connection from xxx to xxx
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.164: 03: --> xxx ESMTP MDaemon 16.0.4; Fri, 12 Aug 2016 06:31:24 +1000
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.164: 03: --> 220-Unauthorized relay prohibited.
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.164: 03: --> 220 All transactions and IP are logged.
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.167: 02: <-- EHLO OCSQL2
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> xxx Hello OCSQL2 [10.10.45.34], pleased to meet you
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250-ETRN
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 PLAIN
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250-8BITMIME
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250-STARTTLS
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 03: --> 250 SIZE
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.168: 02: <-- MAIL FROM:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.170: 01: xxx is an alias for xxx
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.170: 03: --> 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.170: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.175: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.175: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.265: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.266: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.270: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.270: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.275: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.276: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.281: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.281: 02: <-- RCPT TO:<xxx>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.286: 03: --> 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.286: 02: <-- DATA
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.290: 01: Creating temp file (SMTP): e:\mdaemon\queues\temp\md50000008212.tmp
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.290: 03: --> 354 Enter mail, end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.295: 01: Message size: 552 bytes
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.323: 04: Socket error sending response to DATA
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.324: 04: *  Socket error 10054 - Connection was reset by the other side!
Fri 2016-08-12 06:31:24.324: 04: SMTP session terminated (Bytes in/out: 841/540)
```

code in the application:

```
public bool sendUploadNotification() {
        var arrToEmail = toEmail.Split(';');
        var arrCCEmail = ccEmail.Split(';');
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        string body;
        string subject;
        bool result = false;

        if (logger.IsDebugEnabled) { logger.Debug("sending upload email"); }

        try {
            body = ReadBody();
            subject = GetSubject();


            if (logger.IsDebugEnabled) {
                logger.Debug("ToEmail:" + toEmail + "," + "CCEmail:" + ccEmail + ",Subject:" + subject);
            }

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail,fromName);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;        


            foreach (var item in arrToEmail) {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
            }
            foreach (var item in arrCCEmail) {
                msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(item));
            }

            client.Send(msg);
            result = true;

            if (logger.IsInfoEnabled) {
                logger.Info("Upload confirmation email sent");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            if (logger.IsErrorEnabled) {
                logger.Error("Error sending upload confirmation email", ex);
            }
            sendExceptionMail(ex);
            result = false;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

I'm not getting any exception in the application logs, everything is completed successfully.

the server has other .net modules which don't seem to have this problem, however other modules that send out emails are not triggered by SQL agent, they are called at runtime from the website

this problem seems to occur at random, most of the times it doesn't work, sometimes I have recieved the email as expected with no changes to the application or the server

I can't figure out why it's failing, searching google turned up some issue with windows 2008 server regarding tcp / ip stack but I'm on windows server 2012 R2 - the only thing that I can think if it may have to do with permissions, but it works sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation yesterday. For first, you will need to make sure of the email addresses are in correct format. believe me or not it can make you a problem.

```
Using System.ComponentModel;

foreach (var item in arrToEmail) 
{
    if (RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Strings.Trim(Sender), "^\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*$")) 
    {
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(item));
    }
}
foreach (var item in arrCCEmail) 
{
    if (RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Strings.Trim(Sender), "^\\w+([-+.']\\w+)*@\\w+([-.]\\w+)*\\.\\w+([-.]\\w+)*$")) 
    {
        msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(item));
    }
}
```

Second, add the sender to your mail construction. MDaemon is very tricky and touchy.

```
msg.Sender = New MailAddress(credentialUser)
```

Third, Don't close the application too fast or dispose the "client" variable you have (assuming is a SMTPClient object). If the connection was dispose too fast, MDaemon think the 3rd party cancel the operation regardless if the mail structure is on MDaemon Server.

Optional, you can use Async Send Mail in your application. This will give you the confirmation and the right time of an email was sended (or failed).

For Example:

Before client.send(msg); in your code you can add this:

```
// Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.

    smtp.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;

    string userState = "Email Token or any text here to identify your Operation";
    //This line will replace "client.send(msg)" code
    smtp.SendAsync(msg, userState);
```

Somewhere in your code add this delegate:

```
private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
    //  Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
    string token = e.UserState.ToString();
    if (e.Cancelled) {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
    }

    if (e.Error != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
    }       
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try it when I can schedule the changes in